# How do we define electromotive force and potential difference in terms of energy transfer between energy stores?

Tags: energy, electric-current, potential, work

I understand that energy is transferred electrically from the chemical potential store in the battery to internal store of the resistor.

How do we include the energy transfer in the definitions of electromotive force of the battery and potential difference across the resistor

Comment: emf is equivalent to a voltage, and has units J/C. i.e., "how much energy is carried by a given charge". Furthermore, a potential implies a force which implies a change in motion which implies a change in energy.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Which energy store does the charge have?

Comment: @Bearing what do you mean by energy store?

Comment: This is the new concept introduced. https://spark.iop.org/it-helpful-talk-about-electrical-energy

Comment: Resistors don’t store energy, they dissipate it

Comment: It appears to me that what these "stp" people call stores is the same what physicists call "reservoirs". The battery as a "store" of chemical energy in an electric circuit driving the light bulb and providing a given electrochemical potential delivers electric work through the lightbulb as it discharges and its electrons go full circle. The work is fully dissipated into evolved heat and that is absorbed by the atmosphere acting as an entropy (or heat) reservoir whose temperature remains the unchanged.

Comment: This point of view is elaborated [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/773545/meaning-of-thermodynamic-identity/773586#773586)